# Why having Thread reference is fine in Serializable class but initializing it leads to NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization

```
class A implements Serializable{

    int a;
    Thread th;
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public Thread getTh() {
        return th;
    }
    public void setTh(Thread th) {
        this.th = th;
    }

}


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        a.setA(10);
        //a.setTh(new Thread());
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("G:\\Sample1.db")));
            oos1.writeObject(a);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois1 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("G:\\Sample1.db")));
            A a1 = (A)ois1.readObject();
            System.out.println(a1.getA()+" "+a.getTh());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Above code will run normally but If I uncomment a.setTh(new Thread()); it throws NotSerializableException.
As Thread is not Serializable,why the default serialization process did not complain about "th" variable before itself.

Comment: Because `null` is serializable.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread` itself does not implement `Serializable`, but here is an subclass of `Thread` which does:

```
class SerializableThread extends Thread implements Serializable {
  @Override public void run() {}
}
```

A `SerializableThread` is now `Serializable` and a `Thread`, so instances of it can be serialized.

The compiler doesn't know if you will store a non-serializable `Thread` or a serializable `Thread` in a reference (or `null`, which is also serializable), so it doesn't stop you adding a `Thread` field to a class implementing `Serializable`.

You can change the type of your setter method if you want to ensure that you only set a serializable `Thread`, for example:

```
public void setTh(SerializableThread th) {
```

or

```
public <T extends Thread & Serializable> void setTh(T th) {
```

However, it is worth noting that this doesn't guarantee serializability of `th` entirely, since it may transitively contain a reference to a non-serializable instance. That's just one of the limitations of Java's serialization mechanism.

Comment: Very Well Explained. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thread as a class is not serializable, for a lot of very practical reasons, however in theory, on might derive a serializable class from Thread.

I suggest you make th `transient` as it is not meaningful to deserialize an instance of Thread.

Comment: I'd suggest OP just gets the `Thread` out of the class entirely. And stop using `Thread` directly too.